# Interface Control Document examples?

Tags: api, documentation, interface

I am leading a team of fellow student programmers this semester on a long-term project (long enough that I may graduate before it's done).  I've worked with ICD's in an internship, but not everyone on the team has had this experience, and I can't show them the documents I worked with due to a non-disclosure agreement.

Can anyone give links to 'real-world' interface control documents? I could come up with some toy examples on my own, but I would like to show these documents at their most useful.

The main focus of our ICDs will be for interoperability of different hardware components, but all forms of ICD are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

**KNOWLEDGE OBJECTS WEB SERVICE 
INTERFACE CONTROL DOCUMENT**

**Vision**:  To provide data layer support to the *REDACTED (private information)*
applications requiring access to peso.

http://localhost:8080/knowledge_objects/application.wadl 
Returns a Web Application Description Language (WADL) page with information about the knowledge_objects methods.

1. **Get keys by date range** 
   Abstract:  http://:/knowledge_objects/keys/{start}/{end} 
   Example: http://localhost:8080/knowledge_objects/keys/2009-10-27/2010-01-01

Example Return:

```
<Keys> 
  <DocumentID>200800000009</DocumentID> 
  <DocumentID>200800000010</DocumentID> 
  <DocumentID>200800000011</DocumentID> 
  <DocumentID>200800000012</DocumentID> 
  <DocumentID>200800000217</DocumentID> 
  <DocumentID>200800000001</DocumentID> 
</Keys>
```

1. **Get knowledge object by id** 
   Abstract:  http://:/knowledge_objects/{doc_id} 
   Example: http://:/knowledge_objects/200910273200 
   Example Return:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
   <Report> 
     <Documents>

     *REDACTED (private information)*
     </Report> 
   </Documents>`

Comment: The above is just for a simple Restful Web Service I built three years ago.  This was my first stab at an ICD.  It was important and quite useful because it let me (web service builder) and the clients (web service users) clearly define boundaries (operations/results) up front.  Then we started coding and integration was near seamless.